# Canceling pollingInterval on unmount RTK query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I have a `useQuery` hook that makes a request every 1 min and trying to cancel polling once the component is unmounted. The RTK query doesn't seem to have "in-house" way to cancel polling. I know there is `skip`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [cancelPolling, setCancelPolling] = useState(false);
  
  useGetTestQuery(undfined, { pollingInterval: !cancelPolling })

  useEffect(() => {
    () => {
      setCancellPoling(true)  
    }
  }, [setCancellPoling])

}
```

Is there a better alternative to my `useEffect` attempt above or perhaps a built-in way that I somehow didn't find it on the doc?

Comment: Is the polling not stopping on its own when all subscriptions are cleared? AFAIK there's nothing additional you need to do to cancel polling when the component unmounts. What exactly is the issue you are seeing that you think you need to do this?

Comment: it's still making a request to the api even when the component is unmounted

Comment: Queries by default will [persist for a minute](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#keepunuseddatafor) after the last subscriber unsubscribes, e.g. unmounts, in case another components mounts and makes the same query request. Is this perhaps what you are seeing? Or is the polling occurring indefinitely? If the latter do you think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Basically, the issue I am having with is, say I have 2 independent components(A and B). on component A, I am fetching data every 45 secs using `pollinInterval`. Now when I navigate to component/page B it still makes the request every 45 secs. My initial thought was on unmount it'd auto cancel/unsubscribe polling but that doesn't seem to be the case.  

it might take me a bit time to reproduce the issue since it involves navigation and stuff but I'll try to reproduce it. Thanks!

Comment: It might make one last request, but it will definitely stop polling after that.

Comment: We had bug reports, and I thought we had fixed that - so try updating RTK and if that doesn't help maybe open another issue to remind us of it ;)

Comment: @phry Just to confirm, by default polling is cancelled on unmount?

Comment: Yes. Worst case it will make one last poll afterwards.